# NSDate with yyyy-MM-dd format

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

I have this date `2015-11-23 05:00:00 +0000`

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
dateString = dateString.substringToIndex(11)
println("dateString \(dateString)") --> `2015-11-23` -> i need this but in NSDate instead String

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let newDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
println("newDate \(newDate)") ---> `2015-01-23 05:11:00 +0000`?????
```

I need that the end value be a NSDate for send to an api

It seems to make no sense but in the Google Calendar API need to completely ignore the hours and only send yyyy-MM-dd to determine whether the event is all day. And this API only allows in date format.

[Tool](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events)

Comment: So you basically have a `date`object that you transform to a string, just to transform it to a NSDate object again. That's against the concept of NSDate.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. NSDate is a numeric representation of an instant in time. It has no inherent format. You use date formatters to create a display string from a date, or convert a date string (which does have a format) to an NSDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove the time from an NSDate and only keep the date, as NSDate has no concept of such a distinction. As per the Apple doc:

> NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone.

Comment: And that's the correct answer - an NSDate has no format. Asking to get an NSDate in a format makes no sense whatsoever. You use stringFromDate to create strings representing the date in whatever format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Just remove the following line:

```
dateString = dateString.substringToIndex(11)
```

and use:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let newDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
println("newDate \(newDate)")
```